# On systemctl start, "Failed to start gitlab-runner.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Bad message."

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl

Whenever I run `systemctl start gitlab-runner.service` I get,

```
systemctl start gitlab-runner.service 
Failed to start gitlab-runner.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Bad message.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gitlab-runner.service' for details.
```

How can I find more information about this error, what does this mean?

Comment: Maybe try it  `journalctl -u gitlab-runner.service `

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable the unit first,

```
systemctl enable gitlab-runner.service
```

Then I could start it,

```
systemctl start gitlab-runner.service
```

Comment: `systemctl status gitlab-runner.service` will print out the error message in more detail